# SQL Column types in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

so I recently started using Jupyter Notebook.

I use SQL queries and then import my results as dataframes to pandas. 
However, having tried everything I could find on the internet, I am not able to get the type of my table columns using SQL.

I can get the types once imported to pandas using 'type()' but that's a different format than the one used in the database.

Is there a way to directly get it from the database using SQL queries, or do I have to convert it from pandas type ?

Comment: what is your RDBMS - (Oracle/MySQL/MS SQL Server/DB2/PostgreSQL/etc.)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but since we are using Cassandra, it's NoSQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get column type from a SQL query is:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'columnName'
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but it doesn't work for me as I get the following error :


one.exec_sql("""

SELECT DATA_TYPE

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'browser' 

AND COLUMN_NAME = 'browser_type'

""")

ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a code that is I'm going to share with you, it will definitely help you getting column names with their data types from SQL using Jupyter Notebook.

```
for table in table_list:
print('\nTable:',table)
column_info=cur.execute(f'''select column_name, data_type from Information_schema.columns where table_schema=
"music_store" and table_name = "{table}" ''')
for i in cur.fetchall():
    print(i)
```

Here table_list is the list of tables in a Database and music_store is the name of Database.
first create a table_list in which all the tables should be present, then run this code.
All the column names will be printed with their data types, tablewise.
Thanks and Regards